# Javascript Won't Update After Change

Tags: javascript, html, web

In my HTML code, I have an SVG with a rectangle that is connected to a JavaScript function I made. To test the button to see if it works, I made the JavaScript code very simple:

```js
function print() {
    alert("Print Statement.");
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <rect width="100" height="50" x="10" y="10" onclick="print();" />
</svg>
```

This works fine, but when I change the string to print in the print statement, it still prints the previous string (i.e. if it printed "Hello", and I changed it to "World", it would still print "Hello"). I tried the basic steps of refreshing the webpage, making sure the code was saved, and I even deleted the whole function and rewrote it again. It still doesn't update the code. This is a problem because when I start implementing the real functions I need, if I ever need to make a change, it wouldn't update. Any ideas?

(EDITS)

I am using Visual Studio Code for the text editor, and Google Chrome for the browser. The JavaScript code is in a separate file, and is imported in the head tags like this: `<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` The main HTML code is a PHP file because later on, I'm going to be implementing databases into the site.

Comment: create print1 function and try with it

Comment: Provide detail about your setup

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54160176/edit) and provide a [mcve] using the snippet editor `[<>]`

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue or saving issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. What I had to do was change the name of the function in the JavaScript file, but keep the old name of the file in the HTML code:

```js
function print1(str) { //function is now called print1
  alert(str);
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <rect width="100" height="50" x="10" y="10" onclick="print('Hello');" />
</svg>
```

Then, I saved the file and tried running it. It didn't work, so I went back to the JavaScript code and changed the name back, and it worked. I don't understand how that worked, but it did. Thanks to all those that helped!

Comment: The script was possibly cached and the local copy was used instead of the newly edited one. Next time try forcing reloading the script with CTRL+F5 in the browser.

Comment: Give us a thumbs up then!! X